# Lucene to relational mapping for .NET

Tags: .net, sql, lucene, mapping, lucene.net

Is there a Lucene (Lucene.NET) to relational database mapping framework recommended for .NET?

I wanted to use Lucene for search purpose off-loading all search from my relational database.

Comment: You want to map lucene to relational data? You know that relational design is based on deduplication, where lucene indexes are +/- based on data duplication? And additionally, there may exist more than one field with the same name in lucene.

Comment: Well, i thought of, in lucene we have document that we can theoretically treat it as a single relational table.

Comment: There is no schema in lucene.

Answer (score 0):

There are some open source project like 
[SimpleLucene](http://simplelucene.codeplex.com/) but I haven't used any one of them.

As you said you can think of lucene as a single DB table ( `i thought of, in lucene we have document that we can theoretically treat it as a single relational table`). So I don't think that you will need a complex `relational database mapping framework` for a single table. Some extension methods like below can make you start to play  with Lucene.Net.

```
public static class LuceneExtension
{
    public static void Index(this IndexWriter writer, object obj)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();

        obj.GetType()
           .GetProperties()
           .Select(p => new { Name = p.Name, Value = p.GetValue(obj, null) })
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(f=>doc.Add( new Field(f.Name,f.Value.ToString(),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED) ));

        writer.AddDocument(doc);

    }
}
```

---

For example

```
indexWriter.Index(new { text = "some text to index" , id = "555" });
```

would index a document with fields `text` and `id`

Answer (score 0):

You could also check Lucene2Objects [hosted in Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/Lucene2Objects) and with sample introduction article in [my blog](http://davidcondemarin.blogspot.com/2012/03/introducing-lucene2objects.html). Basically allows you to abstract from Lucene and think on objects, you could even annotate your domain entities, like this:

```
[SearchableEntity(DefaultSearchProperty = "Text")]
public class Message
{
 public int Id { get; set; }

 [Indexed]
 public string Text { get; set; }

 [Indexed]
 public string Title { get; set; }

 public DateTime Sent { get; set; }

 public DateTime? Read { get; set; }
}
```

And then, save like this:

```
var iWriter = new IndexWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\index");
var message = new Message { Id = 12, Sent = DateTime.Now, 
                            Text = "Some text on the message!", 
                            Title = "This is the title" 
              };
iWriter.AddEntity(message);
iWriter.Close();
```

And search your index like this

```
var iReader = new IndexReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\index");
var messages = iReader.Search<Message>("text");

foreach (var message in messages) {
 Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", message.Title);
}
```

Sorry if the answer is too long.
Hope I can help!

**DISCLAIMER:** As you may have imagined, I wrote the library.

Comment: Hi David, This was basically what i was kind of looking for. I also created similar library with the addition of "table name" in your searchable Entity class. I raised this tread just thinking i might be re-inventing a wheel and didn't want to spend too much time if there is a tested, ready library. But i think we are on the same page .. :)

Comment: Hey addisu, sounds nice, except that you are tying your design to the concept of a table, which is not nice if you plan to use MongoDB, or any NoSQL alternative at some point..